# Use javascript variable in the qml listview delegate

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I have a ListModel:

```
ListModel {
ListElement {
    name1: "111"
    name2: "222"
    ...
    nameN: "222"
}
```

And in the view delegate,

```
Text { id: test}
Component.onCompleted {
   for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
      test.text = ???
   }
}
```

How to set the ??? value ?

I use test.text = "name" + i, but it show "name1", not "111".

I try a lots, but I could't find the correct answer.

Comment: Take a look at [this section](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#models) and  [this other section](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#view-delegates). You define a model with a set of named variables for each element of the model itself (called `role`s). The delegate should use that very same names to access the actual data. Delegate generation is automatically managed by the view...just read the document provided. Also, provide always a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: It's so hard to understand what you're going to do ... What 'json keys' means here? I see no json at all in your code example. From where came the `nameCount` variable?

Answer (score -4):

OK, any way, I find the solution.
use

```
 test.text = model['name' + i]
```

Comment: Vague question, even vaguer answer. If you want to share your problems (and the relative solutions) you are welcome. Just do it in the right way, with a proper explanation. It would help you and oll the other stackoverflowers. Downvoted.